# How to generate Material Design Color set of selected color programmatically?

Tags: flutter, dart, colors, uicolor, color-scheme

***Question 1.***

Let's assume the selected color is #a85c40.

[image]

Now, how can we generate the Material color with some nearby shade from that picked color. The nearby material shade will be like shade 800.

[image]

***Question 2.***

How to generate a colors sets of all colors with shade500 ?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to generate Material Color shades form a single color then use this code.

```
Color color = Color(0xffaad128);
List strengths = <double>[.05];
Map<int, Color> swatch = {};
final int r = color.red, g = color.green, b = color.blue;

for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  strengths.add(0.1 * i);
}
for (var strength in strengths) {
   final double ds = 0.5 - strength;
   swatch[(strength * 1000).round()] = Color.fromRGBO(
     r + ((ds < 0 ? r : (255 - r)) * ds).round(),
     g + ((ds < 0 ? g : (255 - g)) * ds).round(),
     b + ((ds < 0 ? b : (255 - b)) * ds).round(),
     1,
   );
 }
```

form this [link](https://medium.com/@nickysong/creating-a-custom-color-swatch-in-flutter-554bcdcb27f3)

but if you have darkest or lightest color

```
    Map<int, Color> _generateShades({
     required Color lightest,
     required Color mid,
     required Color darkest,
   }) {
     HSLColor hslLightest = HSLColor.fromColor(lightest);
     HSLColor hslMid = HSLColor.fromColor(mid);
     HSLColor hsldarkest = HSLColor.fromColor(darkest);
     double lightnessDarks = (hslMid.lightness - hsldarkest.lightness).abs();
     double lightnessLights = (hslMid.lightness - hslLightest.lightness).abs();
     return _shader(hslMid, lightnessDarks, lightnessLights);
   }


Map<int, Color> _shader(
    HSLColor hslMid, double lightnessDarks, double lightnessLights) {
  double stepDarker = (lightnessDarks) / 4.0;
  double stepLighter = (lightnessLights) / 5.0;

  List<Color> strengths = [];

  ///dark colors steps
  for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    double strength = hslMid.lightness - (i * stepDarker);
    HSLColor hsl = hslMid.withLightness(strength.clamp(0.0, 1.0));
    strengths.add(hsl.toColor());
  }

  ///light colors steps
  for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    double strength = hslMid.lightness + (i * stepLighter);
    HSLColor hsl = hslMid.withLightness(strength.clamp(0.0, 1.0));
    strengths.insert(0, hsl.toColor());
  }
  Map<int, Color> swatch = {
    050: strengths[0],
    100: strengths[1],
    200: strengths[2],
    300: strengths[3],
    400: strengths[4],
    500: strengths[5],
    600: strengths[6],
    700: strengths[7],
    800: strengths[8],
    900: strengths[9],
  };

  return (swatch);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [tool](http://mcg.mbitson.com/) to generate the colors.

Comment: Please read the question carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `colorScheme:` property of the `ThemeData()` and pass a `ColorScheme()` object where you can set all the desired properties.

This video explains it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZUi3hppgG2s